# Laravel 5.2 Auth Guard Multi Auth Login Attempt Is Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

In this case I want to have double login using multi auth by using guard, here is the auth config code in my laravel apps:

Config/Auth.php

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'petugas' => [
          'driver' => 'session',
          'provider' => 'petugas',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],


'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'petugas' =>[
          'driver' => 'eloquent',
          'model' => App\Petugas::class,
        ]

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
```

In that case I have made the Petugas.php in App folder:

App/Petugas.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class petugas extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $table = 'tbl_petugas';

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

And what I want to do is to log in using If Guard('petugas') here is the code in my controller

App/Http/Controllers/LoginRegisterCtrl.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Auth;
use Hash;
use App\Http\Requests;

class LoginRegisterCtrl extends Controller
{
    public function logout()
    {
      Auth::guard('web')->logout();
      Auth::guard('petugas')->logout();
    }

    public function postRegisterUser(Request $request)
    {
      //insert into users table
        try {
          DB::table('users')->insert(array(
            'id'=>'',
            'name'=>$request->name,
            'email'=>$request->email,
            'password'=>Hash::make($request->password),
            'remember_token'=>'',
            'created_at'=>DB::raw('NOW()'),
            'updated_at'=>DB::raw('NOW()'),
            //'api_token'=>''
          ));

          return redirect('index');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          return 'Data belum lengkap';
        }
    }

    public function postLoginUser(Request $request)
    {
      if (Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' =>$request->password],$request->remember)) {
                // Authentication passed...
                //return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        //return Auth::guard('web')->user()->email;
                return redirect('index');
        }
    }

    public function postRegisterPetugas(Request $request)
    {
      //insert into officers table
        try {
          DB::table('tbl_petugas')->insert(array(
            'id'=>'',
            'name'=>$request->name,
            'email'=>$request->email,
            'password'=>Hash::make($request->password),
            'nik'=>$request->nik,
            'jabatan'=>$request->jabatan,
            'remember_token'=>'',
            'created_at'=>DB::raw('NOW()'),
            'updated_at'=>DB::raw('NOW()'),
            //'api_token'=>''
          ));

          return redirect('admin');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          return 'Data belum lengkap';
        }

        if (Auth::guard('nurse')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' =>$request->password],$request->remember)) {

          }
    }

    public function postLoginPetugas(Request $request)
    {
      // return $request->email.$request->password.$request->remember;
      if (Auth::guard('petugas')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' =>$request->password],$request->remember)) {
                // Authentication passed...
                //return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        // return Auth::guard('petugas')->user()->email;
                return redirect('admin');
        }
        return "salah";
    }
}
```

and the result is returning salah,

is there anything wrong with my current code? Is there any additional configuration to make it works?

Thank you for the answers

Comment: `if (Auth::guard('nurse')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' =>$request->password],$request->remember))` why are you using `nurse` guard ?

Comment: Hi @zorx well, I think that is not relevant since my problem is in postLoginPetugas function, not that, and I will change that too